# kafka stop consuming message from new assigned partitions after rebalancing

Tags: spring, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I'm quite new to kafka (also to english...),I facing this issue and can not google any solutions.

I use spring-boot,spring-kafka support, I have installed kafka_2.11-0.10.1.1 on my local machine (with only one broker 0)

s1.then I create topic by

```
bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 5 --topic tracking
```

My consumer config:
applitions.properties:

```
kafka.servers.bootstrap=localhost:9092 
kafka.topic.tracking=tracking
kafka.group.id=trackingGroup
kafka.client.id=client-1
```

s2. Then i startup 3 consumers by change the 'kafka.client.id' and run spring-boot main class . on eclipse console, I can check the partitions assignment:

```
client-1: partitions assigned:[tracking-4, tracking-3]
client-2: partitions assigned:[tracking-2, tracking-1]
client-3: partitions assigned:[tracking-0]
```

s3. start the pruducer to send 20 messages to the topic, each start to consume message of specific partition

s4. I close the consume 1, kafka do the rebalancing automatically ,
new partitions assignment:

```
client-1: partitions assigned:[]
client-2: partitions assigned:[tracking-2,tracking-1, tracking-0]
client-3: partitions assigned:[tracking-4,tracking-3]
```

s5. I found message on partition 'tracking-3' is no consumed !!

issue can be reproduced every time , aways some messages in new assigned partitions loss, do u can any suggesstions? Please help me ,thanks

Comment: I am not sure at what point you shut down client-1. It is possible that the client-1 has consumed all the messages from tracking-3 before it is shut down. Did you try sending more messages into the topic after you shut client-1 down?

Comment: I press ctrl+c to shutdown client-1, client-1 did NOT consumed all message in tracking-3,  I‘ve try many times with more messages.  but still  loss message

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I reproduced it; it looks like a problem in kafka itself (with `auto.comit.enabled=true`) on the rebalance, kafka is reporting the "position" of the unread partitions (`the offset of the <i>next record</i> that will be fetched (if a record with that offset exists)`) as the end of the partition.

In fact, when I use the kafka-consumer-groups tool, the offsets of the unread partitions are already at the "end". When I run it with just one consumer, while it is reading the first partition, I see...

```
$ kafka-consumer-groups --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --describe -group so43405009

TOPIC                          PARTITION  CURRENT-OFFSET  LOG-END-OFFSET  LAG        CONSUMER-ID                                       HOST                           CLIENT-ID
tracking                       0          37              40              3          client1-8129bb3d-3a83-4c83-9128-3a2762ede758      /10.0.0.6                      client1
tracking                       1          40              40              0          client1-8129bb3d-3a83-4c83-9128-3a2762ede758      /10.0.0.6                      client1
tracking                       2          40              40              0          client1-8129bb3d-3a83-4c83-9128-3a2762ede758      /10.0.0.6                      client1
tracking                       3          40              40              0          client1-8129bb3d-3a83-4c83-9128-3a2762ede758      /10.0.0.6                      client1
tracking                       4          40              40              0          client1-8129bb3d-3a83-4c83-9128-3a2762ede758      /10.0.0.6                      client1
```

Notice the CURRENT_OFFSET column.

On the next run, I ran it twice, once while the first partition is being processed, and again a bit later...

```
TOPIC                          PARTITION  CURRENT-OFFSET  LOG-END-OFFSET  LAG        CONSUMER-ID                                       HOST                           CLIENT-ID
tracking                       0          41              44              3          client1-56d78a4b-f2df-4e31-8c5d-f8a1d8f64cf8      /10.0.0.6                      client1
tracking                       1          44              44              0          client1-56d78a4b-f2df-4e31-8c5d-f8a1d8f64cf8      /10.0.0.6                      client1
tracking                       2          44              44              0          client1-56d78a4b-f2df-4e31-8c5d-f8a1d8f64cf8      /10.0.0.6                      client1
tracking                       3          44              44              0          client1-56d78a4b-f2df-4e31-8c5d-f8a1d8f64cf8      /10.0.0.6                      client1
tracking                       4          44              44              0          client1-56d78a4b-f2df-4e31-8c5d-f8a1d8f64cf8      /10.0.0.6                      client1
```

and

```
TOPIC                          PARTITION  CURRENT-OFFSET  LOG-END-OFFSET  LAG        CONSUMER-ID                                       HOST                           CLIENT-ID
tracking                       0          44              44              0          client1-56d78a4b-f2df-4e31-8c5d-f8a1d8f64cf8      /10.0.0.6                      client1
tracking                       1          44              44              0          client1-56d78a4b-f2df-4e31-8c5d-f8a1d8f64cf8      /10.0.0.6                      client1
tracking                       2          41              44              3          client1-56d78a4b-f2df-4e31-8c5d-f8a1d8f64cf8      /10.0.0.6                      client1
tracking                       3          44              44              0          client1-56d78a4b-f2df-4e31-8c5d-f8a1d8f64cf8      /10.0.0.6                      client1
tracking                       4          44              44              0          client1-56d78a4b-f2df-4e31-8c5d-f8a1d8f64cf8      /10.0.0.6                      client1
```

See how the current offset of partition 2 went down from 44 to 41.

Disabling auto-commit solved it for me...

```
spring.kafka.consumer.enable-auto-commit=false
```

...

```
TOPIC                          PARTITION  CURRENT-OFFSET  LOG-END-OFFSET  LAG        CONSUMER-ID                                       HOST                           CLIENT-ID
tracking                       0          52              52              0          client1-59413599-81e8-49dd-bbd7-8a62152f11e5      /10.0.0.6                      client1
tracking                       1          49              52              3          client1-59413599-81e8-49dd-bbd7-8a62152f11e5      /10.0.0.6                      client1
tracking                       2          49              52              3          client2-edfe34f9-08d5-4825-80d0-4a6cf9526e42      /10.0.0.6                      client2
tracking                       3          48              52              4          client2-edfe34f9-08d5-4825-80d0-4a6cf9526e42      /10.0.0.6                      client2
tracking                       4          51              52              1          client3-20da8742-af38-403e-b125-5d0c7c771319      /10.0.0.6                      client3
```

Here is my test program:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class So43405009Application implements CommandLineRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So43405009Application.class, args);
    }

    @Autowired
    private KafkaTemplate<String, String> template;

    @Value("${spring.kafka.consumer.client-id}")
    private String clientId;

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        if (this.clientId.endsWith("1")) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
                this.template.sendDefault("foo" + i);
            }
        }
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaMessageListenerContainer<String, String> container(ConsumerFactory<String, String> cf) {
        ContainerProperties containerProperties = new ContainerProperties("tracking");
        containerProperties.setMessageListener((MessageListener<?, ?>) d -> {
            System.out.println(d);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5_000);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
        });
        KafkaMessageListenerContainer<String, String> container = new KafkaMessageListenerContainer<>(cf,
                containerProperties);
        return container;
    }

}
```

with properties

```
spring.kafka.listener.ack-mode=record
spring.kafka.consumer.enable-auto-commit=false
spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset=earliest
spring.kafka.consumer.group-id=so43405009
spring.kafka.consumer.client-id=client1
spring.kafka.template.default-topic=tracking
```

I see the same results with 0.10.2.0 as well.

**EDIT**

It turns out to be a spring-kafka bug; it works with auto-commit enabled, but you have to explicitly enable it

```
spring.kafka.consumer.enable-auto-commit=true
```

Otherwise the container assumes it's `false` and causes the above strange behavior - looks like the client doesn't like calling the consumer's commit method if auto-commit is enabled. [#288](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/288).

I would generally recommend setting to false, and choosing one of the container's `AckMode`s instead; e.g. `RECORD` commits after ever record, `BATCH` after every batch received by a poll (default).

Comment: See the edit to my answer for more details of the root cause and a work-around.

Comment: I would like to follow your recommendation ---- "setting to false, and choosing one of the container's AckModes instead; e.g. RECORD commits after ever record, BATCH after every batch received by a poll (default)."   but could u kindly give some code examples or links for that (using spring-kafka) as I really new to kafka and the official spring-kafka docs seems not so sufficient。

Comment: wait ,I just found this can not be solved by simplily add 
    spring.kafka.consumer.enable-auto-commit=true ,     this will cause some messages consumed twice !  e.g.  message m1  is in partition p1 and consumed by consumer c1, at this time ,then I shutdown c1 and p1 is auto-assigned to consume c2,  I found c2 will consume the m1 again .....

Comment: That's why I recommend not using auto-commit - see my answer to set ackmode `spring.kafka.listener.ack-mode=record
spring.kafka.consumer.enable-auto-commit=false`. Or, if using auto-commit reduce `auto.commit.interval.ms` to something less than the default 5000. In any case, you need to deal with the possibility of duplicates. See [the apache kafka documentation](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/). Exactly once delivery is not yet supported by kafka.